# How constructor can receive a variable quantity of parameters?

Tags: solidity, constructor

I'm coding a contract factory that will generates a lot of contracts and each contract will receive the constructor below:

```
 constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory docHash
) ERC20(_name, _symbol) {
    name = _name;
    addHashes(docHash);
}
```

I will pass an parameter in constructor called "docHash" and it should be added in an array using a function that I already coded as "addHashes". However, each contract will receive a different quantity of hashes, It can be 1 hash, 2 hashes, 3 hashes or more and all hashes must be added in the array.

How can I code to constructor receive variable quantities of hashes?

Comment: You could accept an array of string as input paramter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a constructor that checks each hash and if the hash length is > 0 then call the addHashes function.

That way, if you pass a hash that's not null, the function is called, and if the hash is null, it is not called.

You can't pass a variable amount of parameter but you can pass '0x' as a null byte